# Javascript Login for securing assets folder on hosted domain

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I want to create an index.html which fires when someone tries to access files & folders that are on my domain.
For ex.

***www.example.com/user_ini/somefile***

Now i want to keep a index file that validates a user using javascript and if validated allows to access that folder and files else stops them.

> Something similar to router admin access.

**Can .htaccess help me here ?**

I want to do this using javascript and html.
I tried doing this:

```
<form name="login">
Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
{
 /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
 if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd")
  {
    window.open('target.html')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
  }
 else
 {
   alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/
  }
}
</script>
```

Now the folder might have multiple files.
So basically what i want is if the user is valid he can have access to all folders and files or else denied.

Comment: IMHO, checking authority on the client side is not a good idea.

Comment: Should i be using PHP for this ? @HowardWang as i want to keep this simple or else i will have to maintain sessions,

Comment: Everything that is executed on the client side, can be seen in the developer tools of the browser. So there is no way to securing an asset folder using client side code. You will always need to use a server side techique to do that.

Comment: What are the option that i Have ? i mean i want my office support team to have access to those files and not the outer traffic

Comment: If your office team has a know set of IP addresses, and those IP addresses are guaranteed to belong only to your office, then you can allow the access by IP. Otherwise you can use Basic Auth, cookie session, certificate-based  authentication, ... .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PHP` as a `server side` to `authenticate` the user. You can use form action that will call the PHP code on submit the form to authenticate the user and revert back with the `success` or `failure` response.

**Form :**

```
<form name="login" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method = "post">
Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

**PHP File :**

```
     <?php
        $msg = '';

        if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['userid']) 
           && !empty($_POST['pswrd'])) {

           if ($_POST['userid'] == 'testuser' && 
              $_POST['pswrd'] == '1234') {
              $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
              $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
              $_SESSION['userid'] = 'testuser';

              echo 'You have entered valid use name and password';
           }else {
              $msg = 'Wrong username or password';
           }
        }
     ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but How about the access to files and folder how do i  keep a track whether to allow user to access the file or not

Comment: Then you can put check inside valid block based on the user roles.